# Coverage "Pragma: No Cover" does not work for modules in sub folder

Tags: python, coverage.py

I am trying to add "Pragma: No Cover" to modules that do not require coverage. But coverage.py is only recognizing the comment in modules in the root folder. It does not work on modules that are inside sub directories.

**I have tried using the --rcfile and having an omit list under the [run] section and this solves my problem** 
but I would like to understand why the comment wont work in the sub-directories. *[I did not forget adding the exclude_lines config back into my rcfile.]*

```
sb@ubuntu:~/PycharmProjects/TestAutomation$ coverage report TeamCityListener.py 
Name                  Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------
TeamCityListener.py       3      0   100%
sb@ubuntu:~/PycharmProjects/TestAutomation$ coverage report projectapi/lib/py/ProjectApiSessionManager.py
Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------------
projectapi/lib/py/ProjectApiSessionManager.py       2      2     0%
```

** ProjectApiSessionManager class definition:**

```
class ProjectApiSessionManager(SessionManager):       # pragma: no cover

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(projectapi_config_manager.env_info, auth_enabled=True)
```

**TeamCityListener class definition:**

```
class TeamCityListener:     # pragma: no cover
    # bunch of methods
```

The value in the cover column for both the files should be at 100% because both the modules contain only 1 class with the "#pragma: no cover" comment in the same line as the class definition. I have tested by removing the comment from TeamCityListener.py and the cover goes back down to 0%, so I can confirm that it works for the modules in the root directory.

**.coveragerc:**

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
```

Comment: There's no reason the pragma would work in one directory but not another. Something else must be going on.  Are you sure the source code has the pragmas where the report is being generated?